# AngularJS directive to set a temporary variable for intermediate results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a directive that acts similar to JSP's `<c:set var="x" value="${1+1}"/>`? I.e. evaluates an expression and stores the result without producing any output?

I am asking because I want to hold an intermediate result of a very long expression that cannot be easily moved to the controller due to it being used in deeply nested ng-repeat.

Comment: It is hard to recommend something without seeing the code, though ngInit fits the description.

Comment: @estus Yeah, it seems ngInit will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't however what you should do is push that expression into a service if the controller shouldn't handle it for any reason, and then call the service. Because you should populate your View with logic is not the MVC approach.

However if you still want to use the view... you could do something like use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) and [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) in your complex nested directives and `ng-repeats` to pass the value of your model to the corresponding parent

Comment: Unfortunately the long expression is view-specific logic though (trying to patch up a dodgy field from the server with data that is only available at that level of nesting). I can move the logic to a service, but amount of arguments being passed causes a lot of unnecessary complexity.